# How to extract nested ternary operation and assign value to an object key in javascript while maintaining sonarqube test?

Tags: javascript, sonarqube, conditional-operator

I am facing some issue while assigning value to an object key using nested ternary operator during the sonar test,

https://rules.sonarsource.com/javascript/RSPEC-3358

Here is my code:

```
const demoObject={
   demoKey: <condition1> ? <condition2> ? "value1" : demoFunc("value2") ?? "" : ""
}
```

This above code is working fine, but while running sonar test, as the rule says this is not accepted.

But I need to assign value to **demoKey** also cannot use IIFE for assignment.

Comment: The rule already explains why it's wrong and offers simple `if`/`else` as alternative.

Comment: Yes, but to assign a value, I need to run IIFE, like demoKey:(()=>{ return <somevaleu>})(), anything without this type of assignment?

Comment: Why can't you assign a value on the previous (or subsequent) line with a traditional `if`?  You don't need an IIFE.

Comment: `let demoKey = ""; if (something) { demoKey = "whatever"; } const demoObject = { demoKey: demoKey };` - where is the IIFE?

Comment: Cannot do that, as this object is in argument and I am restricted to do so

Answer (score -1):

Finally I got the solution to handle this kind of situation. we can use **&&** and **??** to do this.

Here is the code example:

```
const demoObject={
   demoKey: (<condition1> && 
               (<condition2> ? "value1" : demoFunc("value2") ?? "")
            ) ?? ""
   }
```

Also the brackets are as important as **&&** and **??**